# Meta data (Tags and Categories) for Custom Posts not showing.

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, post-meta, tags

I registered a custom post type ("movie") with tags and categories. Now, I'm able to filter and search for the custom post with these tags and categories, so I know they're present and working, but they're not showing up on the custom posts.

This is the code for the meta data to show up.

```
<?php
if( !myThemes::get( 'show-bottom-meta' ) ){
return;
}
if( is_singular( 'post' ) && ( has_category( ) || has_tag() ) ){
?>
<div class="post-meta-terms">
<?php

if( is_singular( 'post' ) && has_category( ) ){
echo '<div class="post-meta-categories">';
echo '<strong><i class="icon-list"></i> ' . __( 'Categories' , 'myThemes' ) . '</strong>: ';
the_category( ' ' );
echo '</div>';
}

if( is_singular( 'post' ) && has_tag() ){
echo '<div class="post-meta-tags">';
echo '<strong><i class="icon-tags"></i> ' . __( 'Post Tags' , 'myThemes' ) . '</strong>: ';
the_tags( ' ' , ' ' , ' ' );
echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This has only "post" so I added "movies" to make it show the meta data for movies as well, like this:

```
<?php
    if( !myThemes::get( 'show-bottom-meta' ) ){
        return;
    }
    if( is_singular( 'post', 'movie' ) && ( has_category( ) || has_tag() ) ){
?>
        <div class="post-meta-terms">
            <?php

                if( is_singular( 'post', 'movie' ) && has_category( ) ){
                    echo '<div class="post-meta-categories">';
                    echo '<strong><i class="icon-list"></i> ' . __( 'Categories' , 'myThemes' ) . '</strong>: ';
                    the_category( ' ' );
                    echo '</div>';
                }

                if( is_singular( 'post', 'movie' ) && has_tag() ){
                    echo '<div class="post-meta-tags">';
                    echo '<strong><i class="icon-tags"></i> ' . __( 'Post Tags' , 'myThemes' ) . '</strong>: ';
                    the_tags( ' ' , ' ' , ' ' );
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

But it isn't working. I checked this post ([link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141679/showing-meta-data-for-custom-post-types)) but it looks like they follow the same logic, so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for `is_singular()` is wrong

It should be an array

```
is_singular(array('post','movie'))
```

You can read more about the argument passed from this [link here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Comment: Note also that you can call `is_singular()` with no post types defined, ensuring that the function will return `true` for a singular post no matter the post type.

Comment: Thanks, David and Karun! The fix was so easy, I'm embarrassed I didn't see it myself! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in second side of condition

```
... && ( has_category( ) || has_tag() ) { ...
```

try change with

```
... && has_term( null , 'collections' , $post -> ID ) ){ ...
```

where "collections" is slug name for registered custom terms ( custom tags and categories )

also I want recommend you to use other slug name for custom tags and categories for your custom posts eg: movie-tags, movie-categories

Comment: and also is need to change function the_category() and the_tags() with the_terms( $post -> ID , 'collections' , null , '' ); OR the_terms( $post -> ID , 'movie-categories' , null , '' ); AND the_terms( $post -> ID , 'movie-tags' , null , '' );

Comment: File an [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/177635/edit) if you want to add more to your answer.